# Unexpected side effect in "currentData" computed property

Tags: javascript, vue.js

How can I return an array from `computed` in Vue.js?

I am getting this error:

> error  Unexpected side effect in "currentData" computed property  vue/no-side-effects-in-computed-properties...

My code is given below:

```
export default {
  computed: {
    currentData: function() {
      this.series[0].data = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8];
      return this.series[0].data;
    }
  }
};

<template>
  <div>
    {{currentData}}
  </div>
</template>
```

Comment: you change value of this.series[0].data to [1,2,3,4,5,6]... you can't do it in computed.... you can only return data based on your state. that's why

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not a Vue expert, however error you get is quite clear - you should not mutate your state in computed properties. You can only refer to them and generate some readonly response as result. Please check [this link](https://github.com/vuejs/eslint-plugin-vue/blob/master/docs/rules/no-side-effects-in-computed-properties.md). Please remove

```
this.series[0].data=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8];
```

and update it on other place